# Accessing Text within Tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I've got several html structures like this:

```
<div id="some_id" class="bio"> 
  <h3><img src="some.jpg" alt="alt_text" /><br /> 
  <a name="Name"></a></h3> 
  <div class="bio_info"> 
     <h3 class="bio_name">NAME TEXT</h3> 
       <p>BIO TEXT</p> 
       <div class="add_bio">MORE BIO</div> 
  </div> 
  <p><span class="add_bio_toggle">more</span></p> 
</div>
```

and I'm looping though them, accessing them using the 'this' variable. What's the proper way to access the text I have capitalized (NAME TEXT, BIO TEXT, MORE BIO)? I've been trying variations of

```
var bio.name = $('.bio_info.bio_name', this).html();
```

to no avail. What am I missing?

```
[example code]  
   //get the national leadership, by column  
    $('#national_leadership .left_col .bio').each(function(){  
        //create new object to add to nat_leadership array  
      var bio = new Object();  
      bio.id = $(this).attr('id');   
      bio.name = $('.bio_info', this).find('.bio_name').text();
      ...
```

which finds the id fine, but returns an empty string for the name.

Comment: for furthur reading,,go through this http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

Edit after OP's post update:

Example with `each`:

```
$(".bio").each( function()
{
    var bio_name = $(this).find(".bio_name").text()
    var bio_text = $(this).find(".bio_name").next().text());
    var more_bio = $(this).find(".add_bio").text());
});
```

Comment: I know I could access the text by hard-coding the id in the selector, but I guess it's the 'this' that's throwing me... See above edits for and example of the code I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('.bio_name').text();
```

if you are looping through you can use

```
$(this).text()
```

then please see...jquery find()

http://api.jquery.com/find/

```
$('bio).find('.bio_name').text();
```

Comment: but won't that select all the .bio_name elements in the page?

Comment: danwoods if you are looping through you can do $(this).text();

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the elements in the bio_info div and alert the contents if it's a text node (you'll probably want to do something else other than an alert):

```
$(function() {
    $(".bio_info").contents().filter(function() {
        if(this.nodeType == 1) {
            alert($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```